# Ffmpeg and png watermark on OSX error

Tags: ffmpeg, png, codec

I am trying to add watermark with transparent background on OSX with ffmpeg.

I am using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mpg -vf "movie=stuff.png, scale=100:100 [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w:main_h-overlay_h-10 [out]"  out.mpg
```

And I am getting this:

```
ffmpeg version 0.11.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun 12 2012 21:37:10 with clang 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.54)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/0.11.1 --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-libfreetype --cc=/usr/bin/clang --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libxvid --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libass --enable-libvo-aacenc --disable-ffplay
  libavutil      51. 54.100 / 51. 54.100
  libavcodec     54. 23.100 / 54. 23.100
  libavformat    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
  libavdevice    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
  libavfilter     2. 77.100 /  2. 77.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Input #0, mpeg, from 'test.mpg':
  Duration: 00:00:01.04, start: 1.000000, bitrate: 9106 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 104857 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 90k tbn, 24 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
File 'out.mpg' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
w:640 h:480 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/90000 sar:1/1 sws_param:flags=2
[buffersink @ 0x7ff50bc1c3e0] No opaque field provided
[png @ 0x7ff50c038400] unsupported bit depth 16 and color type 4
[image2 @ 0x7ff50c044800] decoding for stream 0 failed
[image2 @ 0x7ff50c044800] Could not find codec parameters (Video: png, 640x480)
[movie @ 0x7ff50bc17200] Failed to find stream info
[movie @ 0x7ff50bc17200] seek_point:0 format_name:(null) file_name:stuff.png stream_index:0
[scale @ 0x7ff50bc178c0] auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted scaler 0' between the filter 'Parsed_movie_0' and the filter 'Parsed_scale_1'
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_movie_0' and the filter 'auto-inserted scaler 0'
Error opening filters!
```

I thought I am missing png support and I checked homebrew for libpng install, but it turn out png support is already included by Apple with OSX.

Also I did

```
ffmpeg -codecs list | grep -i png
```

and I do have PNG support in ffmpeg:

```
DEV D  png             PNG (Portable Network Graphics) image
```

Comment: Is yor file 16bit grayscale with alpha? It looks ffmpeg doesn't support this combination. Try converting it to 8bits and/or RGBA.

Comment: great that actually is the case. Can you post it as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is yor file 16bit grayscale with alpha? It looks like `ffmpeg` doesn't support this combination.  Try converting it to 8bits and/or RGBA.